# How to allow edits to Access database via a Form in the front end of Access Database?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

My access data base form won't let me update data (back end is Access database as well). It shows me a "This Recordset is not updateable" error when I try. Currently the form is pulling records from the back end. Currently the form won't change the original value it pulls from the database; but I want users to be able to update those values.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub CellID_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Command23_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command23_Click


Screen.PreviousControl.SetFocus
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind

Exit_Command23_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command23_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command23_Click

End Sub
Private Sub Command24_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command24_Click


DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Exit_Command24_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command24_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command24_Click

End Sub
Private Sub Command25_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command25_Click


DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Exit_Command25_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command25_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command25_Click

End Sub
Private Sub Command26_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command26_Click


DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious

Exit_Command26_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command26_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command26_Click

End Sub
 Private Sub Command27_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command27_Click


If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.Quit

Exit_Command27_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command27_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command27_Click

End Sub

Private Sub Ctl50th_DC_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub

Private Sub Dc1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

More specifically, looking to update DC1 and 50th_DC

Answer (score 2):

Well, in place of trying to use a bunch of code and forms, FIRST check if you can open a linked table in your front end. If that does not work, then no use trying a complex form or code. So, the linked tables should work. Can you click on a linked table, open it, and see data? If that works, then try while looking/using that open table to edit a record. If you can't from the UI edit records, then code or forms also will not work.

So, test/check by simple opening a linked table.

If you can't edit data, but can see data in a table?

Then this suggests the back end is in a folder in which you don't have create file rights, and delete file rights.

You as a general rule need BOTH create and delete rights in that shared folder in which (where) your back end accdb file resides. If you don't have create file rights, and delete file rights, then in MOST cases, Access will open those tables as READ only - and you can't update them.

So, check the folder permissions where the back end resides.

Comment: I made myself the owner of the back end file as well as the front end file. Still no change? when I open up the query, it doesn't let me edit data there either. For more context: there is a query pulling data from a database and the person before me created a form to edit that data. However data is not updateable

Comment: also when I open linked table manager, it only lets me see the database I've connected to and the tables,, not the actual data in a table if thats what you're implying?

Comment: I am simple suggesting that you click on, and open any of the linked tables. I mean, if a simple click + opening of a linked table does not work, then no use attempting to play with code and forms etc. So, I just suggesting to try and open a linked table. Do they work? Do they display data? And if they display data, then can you edit data in that linked table? Then, and ONLY then do you want to play with and test and try a form, or a form that might have VBA code. So, spend a whole 10 seconds, open a linked table - do they work?

Comment: Yes I am able to open those tables in the backend file, and edit records there directly. However, not when I try to do it with the file containing the form and running the query.

Comment: But we are to test and try the linked tables in the front part. If a simple click and open of a linked table don't work, then little use to try a form. So first step is to open a linked table. There not linked tables in the backend file and thus that's not what I'm asking. You are to try opening a linked table in front end. If they show data, then next step is to try editing in that linked table. If editing in linked table don't work then we can skip next step of trying to open and use a form based on that linked table.

Comment: ok I see what you were saying. Yes I can open the linked table and it shows all the data, and I can even edit it in the front end file. What would the next step be?

Comment: Ok then, that means our links work correctly. This now means the links are ok and now means our form has code or a query or settings that is preventing editing of data. But we have eliminated that this is not issue with links but is now a particular form. This also means that other forms can work but the specific form has some issues. So links work, and are not broken.

Comment: So, next step is the form based on a linked table, or is it based on query? I most likly suggest that the form is not directly using the linked table (and it should be). So, now we can send our network team home. So, now open the query the form is based on? Again, like linked tables, does it show data, but now try editing, can we edit? If we can't edit, then the query the form is based on is at fault. The form does not need to be based on a query, but if it is, and a simple open of that query can't edit data, then the query is "non editable" and that's our issue.

Comment: I can see and edit the data when I run the query

Comment: How do I make it so that the form is using the linked table rather than the query?

Comment: Open the form in design mode, and then from the property sheet change the Record Source setting (a drop down appears). I mean how on earth could you get this far in Access without knowing how to set a forms Record Source? It is a rather basic assumption that this was and is done for each form at one time, right? I mean, it goes without saying that one would first check the forms record source, and say give that forms Record Source a try (open from the tables or queries in the left nav pane), and see how it works, how it goes and if it allows editing of data.

Comment: fyi: I'm not an access expert, but unfortunately inherited quite a few access databases with no documentation in this project.. I fixed the issue by changing the dynaset setting to dynaset (inconsistent changes). record set is now updateable... probably because the query was joining two tables??

Comment: I dont want to set the record source of the form to the table directly, because there is data from two tables in the form